# How to convert a v8::Local<v8::Value> into a uint32_t

Tags: v8

Given the following code how can I convert the v8::Local<v8::Value> into a uint32_t. Or other types based on the Is* method?

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> value;
v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent());
if(value->IsUint32()) {
   v8::MaybeLocal<Int32> maybeLocal = value->Uint32Value(context);
   uint32_t i = maybeLocal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't work because `value->Uint32Value(context)` doesn't return a `v8::MaybeLocal<Int32>`. C++ types are your friend (just like TypeScript)!

You have two possibilities:

(1) You can use `Value::Uint32Value(...)` which returns a `Maybe<uint32_t>`. Since you already checked that `value->IsUint32()`, this conversion cannot fail, so you can extract the `uint32_t` wrapped in the `Maybe` using `Maybe::ToChecked()`.

(2) You can use `Value::ToUint32(...)` which returns a `MaybeLocal<Uint32>`. Again, since you already checked that `value->IsUint32()`, that cannot fail, so you can get a `Local<Uint32>` via `MaybeLocal::ToLocalChecked()`, and then simply use `->` syntax to call the wrapped `Uint32`'s `Value()` method, which gives a `uint32_t`.
If you're only interested in the final `uint32_t` (and not in the intermediate `Local<Uint32>`, which you could pass back to JavaScript), then option (1) will be slightly more efficient.

Note that `IsUint32()` will say `false` for objects like `{valueOf: () => 42; }`. If you want to handle such objects, then attempt the conversion, and handle failures, e.g.:

```
Maybe<uint32_t> maybe_uint = value->Uint32Value(context);
if (maybe_uint.IsJust()) {
  uint32_t i = maybe_uint.FromJust();
} else {
  // Conversion failed. Maybe it threw an exception (use a `v8::TryCatch` to catch it), or maybe the object wasn't convertible to a uint32.
  // Handle that somehow.
}
```

Also, note that most of these concepts are illustrated in V8's [samples](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/samples) and [API tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/test/cctest/test-api.cc). Reading comments and implementations in the API headers themselves also provides a lot of insight.

Final note: you'll probably want to track the current context you're using, rather than creating a fresh context every time you need one.